# Why in angular tutorial I can do 'this.handleError' without pass argument?

Tags: angular

In angular tutorial I have this

```
private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
             .toPromise()
             .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
             .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
  console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
  return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

My question is, how `.catch(this.handleError)` works?

Why I can do `this.handleError` without pass argument?

Comment: its called a callback function.

Comment: according to documentation (reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/…), the 'catch' method takes a function as an argument. This function takes 2 arguments (error, caught). I'm passing 'handleError' function to the "catch" and my handleError receives only 1 argument (error). If I change handleError function to "handleError(error, caught)", still works. How this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a function to another function as a variable. That first function then eventually calls the function you passed it. This is called a 'callback'. Check out this tutorial http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Essentially it works like this.

```
var func1 = function( callback ) {
    callback("hello");
}

var func2 = function( text ) {
    console.log(text);  // hello
}

func1( func2 );
```

Comment: but how the catch knows what arguments must be passed to handleError method in this case?

Comment: This is a really good explanation of what's happening. Definitely a difficult concept to wrap your head around at first...

Comment: It isn't that it knows what to pass, it just always passes the same thing no matter what. What's really important is that the function you give it has to know what it's getting.

Comment: according to documentation (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-catch), the 'catch' method takes a function as an argument. 

This function takes 2 arguments (error, caught). 

I'm passing 'handleError' function to the "catch" and my handleError receives only 1 argument (error). 

If I change handleError function to "handleError(error, caught)", still works. 

How this is possible?

Comment: That's a feature of Javascript function parameters. Before using typescript it's useful to know how javascript works. Functions can be passed more arguments than are defined in their "signature." catch will always pass error and caught, in that order, but your handleError can look like this `handleError(e)`, this: `handleError(e, c)` or even this, `handleError(e, c, t, o, p, l, a, s, m)`. In the last case if you try to console.log anything after c it will be undefined.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain I was thinking like you, but when I add a new param to method signature, I get this error: "Argument of type '(a: any, b: any, c: any) => ErrorObservable' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Response>) => ObservableInput<any>'." Only works if the signature have 1 or 2 argument. I can't understand this.

Comment: My bad, at that point I was still talking about javascript.  Typescript is an attempt to make Javascript more strongly typed and you have the ability to specifically typecheck method calls. The compiler will throw an error if you don't match the number/type of arguments in a function's signature. If it helps you, think about it as a function overloading. Check the bottom of this page.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Typescript compilation will handle it for you.
The equivalent code will look as

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
             .toPromise()
             .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
             .catch(funtion(error)  {
                   console.error('An error occurred', error); 
                   return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

**Note**:For understanding I compiled the `catch` part alone and not the full functionality.

However, if you want to explicitly instruct the argument, you can use as below,

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
         .toPromise()
         .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
         .catch((response)=> {
                    this.handleError(response);
         });
}
```

Comment: but how the catch knows what arguments must be passed to handleError method in this case?

Comment: i didnt get your question

Comment: according to documentation (reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/…), the 'catch' method takes a function as an argument. This function takes 2 arguments (error, caught). I'm passing 'handleError' function to the "catch" and my handleError receives only 1 argument (error). If I change handleError function to "handleError(error, caught)", still works. How this is possible?